# Any online link for sri vidya related strotra (bala, lalita etc) with english meaning?

Tags: stotra, sri-vidya

Is there any site which has sri vidya related strotras with english meanings also. Some places have sanskrit text but no meanings.

Comment: What is sri vidya stotra? It is unclear to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can get many such Stotras on [Hindupedia.com](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Stotra#Prayers_addressed_to_mother_Goddess). It has transliterated Stotras along with English translations.

- For Bala Tripura Sundari:

[Here](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Bala_satha_nama_stotram) is Bala Sata Nama Stotram.

[Here](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Bala_Tripurasundari_Pancharathnam) is Bala Pancharatnam.

- For Lalita Tripurasundari:

[Khadgamala Stotram](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Devi_Gadgamala_stotram).

[Lalita Mula Mantra Kavacham](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Lalitha_Moola_Manthra_Kavacham).

[Lalita Sahasranamam](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Lalitha_Sahasranamam).

[Lalita Pancharatnam by Adi Shankara](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Lalitha_Pancha_Rathnam).

[Lalita Stava Raja](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Lalitha_Sthava_Raja).

[Lalita Trisathi](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Lalitha_Trishathi).

You can also get the short Stotram called Lalita Panchavimsati Nama Stotram with it's meaning in English from [this page](http://manotha.blogspot.com/2012/12/sri-lalita-panca-vimshati-nama-stotram.html). Hindupedia.com does not have this one.

Just to let you know, besides these Stotras, there are many other SriVidya Stotra/Kavachas from the Tantras. These Stotras are not found online. I got them from the book Brihat Tantrasara.

Comment: Excellent collection of sri vidya related strotras in sanskrit is given at https://www.kamakotimandali.com/stotra/stotra_index.html

Comment: Yes i know about that page but u wanted translations in English too.. @Saurabh

Comment: Also if u simply want the Stotras in Sanskrit or transliterated Sanskrit then there are some other good sites too for that. For example Bharatiweb.com is a very good site. But u won't get translations over there, that's a problem. @Saurabh

Comment: Yes the main issue is no english translation otherwise it would be a delight to read them.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the link https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/tripurasun8mean.html?lang=sa

it has the strotrams and the respective meaning/translation in  English.

It has Tripurasundari Ashtakam. Hope it helps.